# What secrets.json to use for Google Assistant samples?

Tags: google-assistant-sdk

I went through the instruction at 
https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/library/python/embed/register-device

To create the secrets json for my device. However, when I try to register it with

> google-oauthlib-tool --scope
>   https://www.googleapis.com/auth/assistant-sdk-prototype --scope
>   https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gcm --save --headless --client-secrets
>   client.json

It gives me this error;

> This app is not yet configured to make OAuth requests. To do that, set
>   up the app’s OAuth consent screen in the Google Cloud Console.

If it then use the downloaded json from the Cloud console instead, I can reigster, but then it results it this;

```
ERROR:root:Failed to register device: {
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Could not create the device instance. Project_id from side channel and project_id from url do not match.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

I can't figure out which of these two jsons, the device or the cloud one, is the right one to use, since they end with different errors at different places.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first setup the project's [OAuth consent screen](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/consent) in the Google Cloud console. For this, you pretty much just need to put an email, as other fields are optional.

Then you will be able to run the google-oauthlib-tool.